# GCP ci/cd: skaffold cannot access private git repository using google cloud build

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, skaffold

I'm trying to configure auto ci/cd process with google cloud platform.
So I went through this instruction https://davelms.medium.com/automate-gke-deployments-using-cloud-build-and-cloud-deploy-2c15909ddf22 and all works good. So I have a trigger in cloud build that goes to cloud build file that using skaffold for manifest rendering. It builds an image and deploy the app. All good.
But as we have a lot of apps we want to have deploy configs in the separate repo. In that case I see from skaffold docs [https://skaffold.dev/docs/references/yaml/?version=v2beta29#build-artifacts-docker-ssh](https://skaffold.dev/docs/references/yaml/?version=v2beta29) that you could use as configs:

```
requires:
  - configs: []
    git:
      repo: https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold.git
      path: skaffold.yaml
      ref: main
      sync: true
```

this config works for public repo, but for private repo I get error:

```
error parsing skaffold configuration file: caching remote dependency https://github.com/your_repo.git: failed to clone repo: running [/usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/your_repo.git ./P7akUPb6jdsgjfgTnOedB92BH8UE7 --branch main --depth 1]
```

```
" - stderr: "Cloning into './P7akUPb6jdsgjfgTnOedB92BH8UE7'...\nfatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address\n""
```

Where or how I could add details for accessing private repo?

Comment: looks like there is config file issue is there anywhere this set ? `https://github.com/your_repo` also username issue so make sure username or github is authorised with cloud build to clone the repo.

Comment: How or where to autorize? because for cloud build you could autorize in web tab for using trigger(but I still get that error for skaffold) or you could use ssh for cloud build file but it's not for skaffold, so also still getting an error

Comment: yes if you auth from web it's good but hope there is no config issue in your build file right ? as repo URL look weird or you have edited in question instead original ?

Comment: it's not real repo url. and all configs for ci-cd works with cloud build and skaffold files when it's in one repo or when configs is in public repo, but not for private repo

Comment: so when this repo https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold.git is private then I got an error. (git repo is as example and it's from skaffold docs that I mention in description of the problem)